# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am migrating an application from MS Visual Studio 2005 to MS Visual Studio 2012 and found this error message:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

I don't know exactly what to do. I have the dll on the project bin but still doesn't seems to work. I tried to search in NuGet and Microsoft site maybe I need to install the latest version, maybe that's what's missing.. but still no luck, Unfortunately, I can't find the installer or any latest version.

Does anyone encounter this error? Please help what to do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Enterprise Library 5.0 can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15104. Enterprise Library 6.0 can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38789. You could try downloading and installing one of those versions, and then removing and readding a reference to the `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration` assembly.

Comment: Didn't work when I install 'EnterpriseLibrary6-source.exe'

Comment: Get the binaries instead. And you'll need to redo the reference.

Comment: I have this on my web.config
`<section name="enterpriselibrary.configurationSettings" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.ConfigurationManagerSectionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />` 
Should I remove? Or change to something else. I think the answer to my question is just under my nose, I can't just pint-point what to do exactly. It maybe too much but step-by-step would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to install the latest version of enterprise library for that, you can download it here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=38789

update: its better to install using nuget package manager. run this command instead:

```
Install-Package EnterpriseLibrary.Common
```

Comment: Got that and installed 'EnterpriseLibrary6-source.exe'. And it created a folder Lib with the following dll: Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.Design.HostAdapter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.Design.HostAdapterV5, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.Design.HostAdapterV5, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.DesignTime, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.DesignTime 

Still getting the error message.

Comment: I can't find the EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration under NuGet

Comment: Yes. I got this error msg.

Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'EnterpriseLibrary.Common 6.0.1304.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that 
targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that 
framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package EnterpriseLibrary.Common
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package],

Comment: you will need to change your projects target framework, it not related to enterprise library, change your projects framework to neither .net 4.5 or you can install the lower version of enterprise library like 5.5

Comment: change .NET Framework to 4.5 and it installed successfully but still getting error in build solution

Comment: Thanks! after installing Enterprise Library 6.0, i make sure all my project is in 4.5 Framework.. Here is the step-by-step process to install and configure the Enterprise Library [link]https://randylevy.wordpress.com/2013/04/30/enterprise-library-6-installation-and-vs2012-configuration/ I basically migrate the project again and when i run.. no errors anymore.